# LINQ to Entity problem. Self-referencing entity

Tags: linq-to-entities, self-reference

I have a Self-referencing entity (0 to *).
When i tried to delete one, got an error.

The structure of data is:

servise1
--service 1.1
--service 1.2
---service 1.2.1
---service 1.2.2
---service 1.2.3
--service 1.3
--service 1.4
service 2

and so on...

I just need to delete one of the services with all subservices (cascade).

Please, help me! )

Comment: You "got an error"? Please post the error. We are not psychics.

Comment: An easy way to get around that is to add an "on delete cascade" on the self referencing foreign key.

Comment: got this error when tried to add cascade: FK_categorycategory' on table 'categories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the on delete cascade to the sql table definition try changing it back to on delete no action, then go to your entity model, select the association in the designer and set the delete to cascade in the properties window.

If that still doesn't work then you could always loop through all of the child services and delete them before calling savechanges.

Comment: Just wanted to mention: setting cascade delete in the entity model does not concern the database, only objects in memory will be removed, so the model would be "in sync" with the DB, if that had executed the cascade. But next time you load the table, the deleted references will be back again.